# What's the semantic content of the word "yo" in the speech of Jesse from Breaking Bad, and in which dialects is this construct found in the real world

Tags: american-english, word-usage, slang, dialects, semantics

So I've been watching breaking bad.  A really interesting dialectical feature of the character Jesse, is his use of the word "yo".

At first I thought nothing of it, it's just "slang" or whatever; nothing to see here...  However, the more I think about it, the more the actual semantics of it seem quite interesting.

#### Background:

The following uses are both relatively transparent:

He of course uses the meaning of *yo* that we're all most familiar with (as a greeting), as in:

> "Yo!   Anybody home?"

Also, at the beginning of a sentence, as a synonym of the exclamation "Hey!", as in:

> “ It's like: ‘ Yo!  Whatever happened to truth in advertising? ’ ”

This meaning, again, is easy to grasp.

#### Usage in question:

However, it also comes up in a completely different way.  Usually, but not always at the end of a sentence, as a sort of emphatic interjection.

For example:

> "C'mon, yo!"
>
> "I mean it, yo!"
>
> "Let me tell you something yo."
>
> "That is messed up yo..."
>
> "Maybe this isn't such a good idea yo..."

In a way it reminds me of a tag question, or the way some dialects use "right" as in:

> "So, I'm at the pub, right, and this guy comes up to me right, and I'm looking at him thinking, ‘ Who are you? ’.  So anyway, right, I say to him..." etc.

But this isn't exactly it.  "Yo!", does't work in the above example for "right". "right?", "know what I'm saying?", and other similar constructions are used to engage the listener, as an informal speech punctuator that essentially means "I want to verify you are engaged, and following what I'm saying.". Jessie's "Yo" carries a different meaning than that, and while I subjectively *understand* it when I hear it, it's difficult to pinpoint exactly what it is.

I can't think of another word or exclamation that fits in all the places where Jesse would say "Yo", and I can't seem to "crystallise" exactly what either the rules of its use, or what it exactly *means*.  Is this use the same as (and borrowed from) its use in AAVE dialects, or is this something different?

Comment: ***Yo***: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=yo - https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/yo

Comment: ***Yo***
(interjection) :

A greeting or said to get someone's attention; hey: Yo, dudes and babes! - 

[1859+; even though yo and yoho are very old utterances, found by 1420, the recent revival of yo as a primarily black interjection has spawned comment; Ernest Paolino of Philadelphia, indignant because a New York writer had claimed the syllable for New York, recalls it from the 1930s as shortening of walyo; in the WWII Army it was the common form of here! used in responding to roll-calls] http://www.dictionary.com/browse/yo

Comment: I will note that interjections such as "yo" are reputed to be old nautical terms, along the lines of "ahoy".  (But such a simple expression could have been re-invented many times, as, eg, a shortening of "yo momma".)

Answer (score 1):

Replace "Yo" with "Dude"

> "C'mon, Dude!"
>
> "I mean it, Dude!"
>
> "Let me tell you something dude."
>
> "That is messed up dude..."
>
> "Maybe this isn't such a good idea dude..."

Yo is being used as a pronoun for another person in the conversation, or as the general idea of a person if talking to himself.

Other words that would fit, for example: "Man", "Girl", "Sir", "Officer", "Bossman" (if you're feeling street).

Examples of where this construction might be used in the real world, with [Yo] being placed next to the word that is replacing it:

> "C'mon Officer [Yo], I don't deserve a ticket"
>
> "We need to get to front if we want to see the show, man [Yo]."